# Python/Numpy combining four matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'd like to combine four matrices with Python/Numpy.

For example, with MATLAB I can do

```
a = [1 1; 1 1];
b = [2 2; 2 2];
c = [3 3; 3 3];
d = [4 4; 4 4];

m = [a b; c d]
```

Then I got

```
 m =

 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     2
 3     3     4     4
 3     3     4     4
```

I am wondering how do I do this with Python/Numpy(easy way)? Thanks.

Comment: looking at [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html) it appears the semicolon in matlab is a row seperator

Comment: Python does not have matrices, you might want to have a look at the numpy library though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.block()`:

```
In [3]: a = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])

In [4]: b = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])

In [5]: c = np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])

In [6]: d = np.array([[4,4],[4,4]])

In [7]: np.block([[a,b],[c,d]])
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```